# What is an unregistered parameter in a UrlQuerySanitizer?

Tags: android, url, query-string

Referring to the Android documentation for `UrlQuerySanitizer`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer.html#getallowunregisteredparamaters

```
open fun getAllowUnregisteredParamaters(): Boolean

open fun setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(allowUnregisteredParamaters: Boolean): Unit
```

> Get whether or not unregistered parameters are allowed. If not
>   allowed, they will be dropped when a query is parsed.

What does that mean and why would you want to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the methods, it seems like registering parameters allows them to **be detected** when parsing the url.

Calling this return `null`:

```
sanitizer.parseQuery("crcat=test&crsource=test&crkw=buy-a-lot")
sanitizer.getValue("crcat")
```

While calling this returns `"test"`:

```
sanitizer.registerParameter("crcat", UrlQuerySanitizer.getUrlLegal())
sanitizer.parseQuery("crcat=test&crsource=test&crkw=buy-a-lot")
sanitizer.getValue("crcat")
```

When you register a parameter, you are specifying the url encoding that is expected in the string.

So by calling `setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(true)`, you do not need to manually register each parameter you want parsed.